# MySQL Unique values for 2 or more dates

Tags: mysql

I'm using a barcode scanner to scan qr codes from tickets for an event, this will be posted to a database with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attendees` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`attendeeguid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`scanned` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `attendeeguid` (`attendeeguid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

Now this attendeeguid has to be unique, but if an event is 2 or more days, it should be possible to scan this attendeeguid again on another date. How can I do this?

I'm using MySQL and I'm using this in an Objective-C iOS App.

Comment: is my qr code different than your qr code upon scan (may seem like a dumb question but what do I know)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Either `attendeeguid` is unique or it is not.  We can't make that decision for you.

Comment: On our events you'll get a ticket with a QR Code in it, this QR Code is in fact a VCard, this contains your name and stuff, but also contains an attendeeguid. Now I managed to make the attendeeguid unique, so it can only be scanned once. But if the event for example last 2 days, it will give an error if the code is being scanned again on day 2...